# New to Ubuntu and the Terminal. Looking for Terminal Tutorials. Suggestions?

Tags: command-line, 16.04

Going in to IS. A friend suggested I learn Linux first. Just looking for a tutorial that will give me the basics of the Linux terminal. I've been playing with cheat sheets and just doing random stuff. Is there something that can guide my learning?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, [Google](http://www.google.com) is your best friend. You can find almost anything to help you with the terminal, but just to start you off there are websites that offer free E-Books for learning the Linux Terminal(more accurately, to learn the command line, BASH). You can sign up [here](http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php) and [here](http://itsfoss.tradepub.com/free/w_syst05/prgm.cgi?a=1) to get free books to learn.

If you prefer videos, I watched [Bucky's Videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGCkg2uj3PxUWhMDuTw3VKjM), they are pretty good for beginners.

Remember, the terminal is your best friend in Linux. And if you don't know? Just Google it!